# How do I get the user when logs incorrectly with Spring Security?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring security for interceptor to user wrong logged, but I can not find the way to do.

I specifically want to save the user logged in last, but I can't figure out how to achieve this.

**Please help me**.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do that. You can define following tag in  tag in your configuration xml file.

```
<security:form-login login-page="/sessionexpired" 
login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" 
default-target-url="/submitLogin" 
always-use-default-target="true" 
authentication-failure-handler-ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>
```

You can see the last parameter set **authentication-failure-handler-ref** its value is a refenrece to following bean defined in the same xml file.

```
<bean id="customAuthenticationFailureHandler" class="com.xxx.xxx.xxx.CustomFilter">
        <constructor-arg type="String" value="loginfailed"></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg type="org.hibernate.SessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></constructor-arg>        
</bean>
```

The class defined in this bean is your own class that will get the information about the failed login details.

```
public class CustomFilter extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    private String defaultFailureUrl;      
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    public CustomFilter(String defaultFailureUrl,SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        super();
        this.defaultFailureUrl = defaultFailureUrl;
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String userName = request.getParameter("j_username");;
        /*System.out.println("CustomFilter Begins");        
        System.out.println("CustomeFilter.username :: " + userName);
        System.out.println("getMessage :: " + exception.getMessage());
        System.out.println("exception :: " + exception.getClass().getSimpleName());
        System.out.println("RemoteAddr :: " + request.getRemoteAddr());        */
    }
}
```

When the Authentication will be failed then method `onAuthenticationFailure` of this class will be called and you can get the user details there to log in database or log file.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.